# XCTestCases are code testing, function testing or functionality testing?

Tags: xctestcase

I am writing Unit test cases for my developed project. I am new in XCTest cases. But when I started writing XCTestCases most of the time I am just coping my function and paste them in XCTest case and check with XCTAssertTrur or XCTAssertNotNil or with other XCTestfunction. My confusion is only copy-paste is the process to test a function or any other things can be done in XCTests cases.